# Determining the proper table on a page using .index

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am developing a simple jQuery solution for a client that will carry information over from a table on this page: http://yft.ac/upcoming-workshops/, to the "Workshop Interested" field on this page: http://yft.ac/contact-us/. I am doing this using the Local Storage API but am running into a problem.

You will notice that if you click any of the three buttons under the "YFT Admissions Insights" heading, that all of the information is being carried over to the required input. However, whenever you click a button underneath the "YFT Intensive Application Workshop", only *some* of the information is being carried over, and whenever you click under the "YFT Head Start", none of the information is being carried over.

Here is the code I am working with:

**Upcoming Workshops Page:**

```
jQuery(function ($) { 
    $('body').on('click', 'a.button', function () { 
        // Variables
        var index = $(this).parents('table').index('table'); 
        var buttonIndex = $("a.button").index(this);
        buttonIndex+=1; //Add one to our index so we ignore the <tr> values in the <thead>

        var cur_workshop_name = $(this).parents('.innercontent').find('h3').eq(index).text(); 
        var cur_workshop_date = $(this).parents('.innercontent').find('tr:nth-of-type(' + buttonIndex + ') td:first-child').eq(index).text(); 
        var cur_workshop_location = $(this).parents('.innercontent').find('tr:nth-of-type(' + buttonIndex + ') td:nth-of-type(3)').eq(index).text(); 

        //Set Item in Local Storage
        localStorage.setItem('workshop', cur_workshop_name + ' | ' + cur_workshop_location + ' | ' + cur_workshop_date); 
    }); 
});
```

**Contact Us Page:**

```
jQuery(function ($) { 
    //Output value in respective field
    $('#workshop').val( localStorage.getItem('workshop') );
});
```

I really pieced this together using my intermediate skills in jQuery, but I think that the problem is happening because of either the multiple tables on the page (there are three), or multiple instances of the `innercontent` class (there are three).

I would appreciate any and all help in sorting this little problem out, thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider using the :nth-child(n) selector to single out the different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplfy that a lot by navigating the DOM tree a little differently.

```
jQuery(function ($) { 
    $('body').on('click', 'a.button', function (event) { 
        var btn   = $(this);
        // get the closest table (unlike parents() this will go up the tree until it finds the first matched element and returns just that)
        var table = btn.closest('table');
        // get the closest row to the button (same as for the table)
        var row   = btn.closest('tr');

        // the find the h3 by searching the previous siblings and stopping at the closest (using :first)
        var cur_workshop_name     = table.prevAll('h3:first').text(); 
        // using the parent row search the child td elements for the required data
        var cur_workshop_date     = row.children('td:first-child').text(); 
        var cur_workshop_location = row.children('td:nth-child(3)').text(); 

        //Set Item in Local Storage
        localStorage.setItem('workshop', cur_workshop_name + ' | ' + cur_workshop_location + ' | ' + cur_workshop_date); 
    }); 
});
```

Here's an example that displays the retrieved values for each button clicked: http://jsfiddle.net/jVJjZ/embedded/result/

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and the detailed comments to help me understand what you did. This works perfectly.